# tm crashing R when converting VCorpus to corpus

Tags: r, tm, corpus

I am using windows 7 with a 32-bit operating system with 4Gb RAM of which only 3Gb is accessible due to 32-bit limitations. I shut everything else down and can see that I have about 1Gb as cached and 1Gb available before starting.  The "free" memory varies but is sometimes 0.

Using tm -  I am successfully creating a 517Mb VCorpus three .txt documents from a Swiftkey dataset. When I attempt to take the next step to convert it to a "corpus" using the `tm::Corpus()` command,  I get an error.  Code and output follows:

```
cname <- file.path("./final/en_US/")
docs <- Corpus(DirSource(cname)) 
myCorpus <- tm::Corpus(docs)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

....and R terminates........any ideas how to prevent this?

Comment: not sure if its related but your function calls weren't capitalized correctly, I've  submitted an edit.

Comment: looks like you run out of memory. Try with a 1 txt document and see what happens.

Comment: thanks....I will try a smaller document

Comment: Thanks phiver....I created three small text files and was able to create the corpus without hitting the error.  I wonder how to get around the memory error as the files are not that unusually large or uncommon.